# How to download a file and move it VB

Tags: vb.net, minecraft

Okay, so I am trying to download this file `https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.6.4/minecraft_server.1.6.4.exe`

and put it here `C:\ServerMaker\Vanilla`

But when I press the button it just does nothing.

Here is the code it is mucking up with :

```
Private Sub Button3_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     Button3.Click

        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.6.4/minecraft_    server.1.6.4.exe", "C:\ServerMaker\Vanilla")


End Sub
```

Comment: There are some spaces in `minecraft_    server.1.6.4.exe`. They may be screwing your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces in the name of the file you are trying to download, remove the spaces :

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.6.4/minecraft_server.1.6.4.exe", "C:\ServerMaker\Vanilla\minecraft_server.1.6.4.exe")
```

***Note that the destination filename must be included*** .

Comment: @user2792832 You have to add another question for this other problem, and take a look here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235